# Deployement Issue

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis-7, sharepoint-2010, iis-7.5

Deployment Issue in IIS 7.0 on Sharepoint 2010 Server .

I am trying to deploy Asp.net Web Application on IIS 7.0 .

As Below :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483479.aspx
[image]

[image: When Creating package and then Deploy]
ERROR 2:

Answer (score 0):

Seen this before (let me guess - this was working on SP2007?).
In any case, you need to remove your script resource handler sections since they are already defined (I don't remember the exact specifics but this bit me in the past). We were using the ASP.NET Ajax Extensions for .NET 2.0 and while things worked fine in 2007 we got this exact issue in 2010.

Here is a copy of the config file we ultimately used so you can see what has been removed:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.aspx"></customErrors>


<pages>

  <controls>

  </controls>

</pages>



<!--

      Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging

      symbols into the compiled page. Because this

      affects performance, set this value to true only

      during development.

-->

<compilation debug="false">

  <assemblies>

    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

  </assemblies>

</compilation>



<httpHandlers>

  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>

  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>

</httpHandlers>



<httpModules>

  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

</httpModules>
```

```
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

     <dependentAssembly>

         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>

             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>

     </dependentAssembly>

     <dependentAssembly>

         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>

         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>

     </dependentAssembly>

 </assemblyBinding>
```

```
<scripting>

  <webServices>

  </webServices>

  <!--

  <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />

  -->

</scripting>
```

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>

<modules>



</modules>

<handlers>

  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />







</handlers>
```